# VS Code Snippets

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to write my own snippets in vscode. I was wondering, if it is possible to add variables such as Rigidbody and Animator and reference them with `GetComponent()` method all inside `Start()` function separately at any time during development without creating the `Start()` function repeatedly (See the code below). Does anybody know?

```json
"Rigidbody": {
    "prefix": "rb",
    "body": ["Rigidbody $1;",
        "",
        "",
        "void Start(){",
                "\t$1 = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();",

        "}"]
},

"Animator":{
    "prefix": "anim",
    "body": ["Animator $1;",
    "",
    "",
    "void Start(){",
        "\t$1 = GetComponent<Animator>();",
    "}"]
}
```

Comment: when retreiving components, try to do it in `Awake()` but yes it should be possible